# VRLA battery in closed container?

Tags: power-supply, safety, lead-acid, underwater

I've just started a new "sunday project", the aim of which is to build an ROV. I was wandering if I could use my spare VRLA battery (NEXON XT line 12v/33Ah) as an onboard power supply. Do these batteries emit hydrogen during work? Can I put it safely in sealed box and not worry about it exploding underwater?

Comment: What does the product safety sheet tell you about usage in confined spaces?

Comment: with a part number I have had good luck here: https://www.msdsonline.com/sds-search/

Comment: It may emit hydrogen when charging.